# Copying an App Bundle

Tags: objective-c

I have a cocoa wrapper that does some configuration and then copies an app from its Resources folder to /Applications. The copy is not working. Here is the code that performs the copy.

```
-(BOOL)copyAppBundle

NSError * error;
BOOL isDir;
//get path to application bundle
NSBundle * mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString * appSrcPath = [[mainBundle bundlePath]stringByAppendingString:@"/Contents/Resources/Bogus.app"];
NSString * appTgtPath = @"/Application/Bogus.app";

if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:appSrcPath isDirectory:&isDir])
{
    //copy the bundle to /Applications
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager]copyItemAtPath:appSrcPath toPath:appTgtPath error:&error];
}

//check the results
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:@"/Application/Bogus.app"])
{
    appCopyResults = TRUE;
}

return appCopyResults;
```

The copy is failing. Is there a step that I am missing or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: How is it failing? Do you get an error or does it just not do anything? I would recommend putting in some `NSLogs` and see where which ones it prints out.